# Error in DESeq formula nbinomTest

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm using the DESeq package to analyze RNA sequencing data. I have only one replicate and two treatments. My code is:

```
data <- read.csv()

metadata <- data.frame(row.names = colnames(data), condition =c("treated", "untreated"))

cds2 <- newCountDataSet( countData = data, conditions = metadata )

cds2 <- estimateSizeFactors(cds2)

counts( cds2, normalized=TRUE )

cds2 <- estimateDispersions(cds2, method="blind", sharingMode="fit-only")

res <- nbinomTest(cds2, "treated", "untreated" )
```

Everything works fine until I call "estimateDispersions". However, the function "nbinomTest" gives me this error:

Error in if (dispTable(cds)[condA] == "blind" || dispTable(cds)[condB] ==  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I found some documentation on this error, but the answers are not helpful for me. I work with R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31).

Can someone help my with my problem, please?

Cheers!

Comment: Is this error still occurring, on current versions of everything?

Comment: In the end I didn't use DESeq but its new version DESeq2, which did not use this code anymore. So I didn't find any solution to the problem but also didn't depend on it anymore, either.